# Question about a definition about explicitly generating groups by arbitrary subsets

Tags: group-theory

The following exercise is taken from the text: Algebra: Groups, Rings, and Fields by Louis Rowen.

Given any subset $S$ of $G$, define the subgroup $\langle S \rangle$ generated by $\textit{S}$, by the following inductive procedure:

1. $S(1)=S$
2. $S(i+1)=S(i) \cup \{gh^{-1}\mid g,h\in S(i)\}$
3. $\langle S \rangle=\bigcup_{i\geq 1} S(i)$  (in $G$)

$\langle S \rangle < G,$ ($S$ is a subgroup of $G$) for if $g,h\in \langle S \rangle,$ then $g,h\in S(i)$ for some $i$, implying $gh^{-1}\in S(i+1)\subset \langle S \rangle.$  On the other hand every subgroup f $G$ containing $S$ contains $\langle S \rangle$.

From 2 of the definition of $i,$ $S(i+1)=S(i) \cup \{gh^{-1}\mid g,h\in S(i)\}$, implies that $gh^{-1}\in S(i+1)$ and by property 3, $gh^{-1} \in  \langle S \rangle$ for some $i$.

I am having trouble seeing what $\bigcup_{i\geq 1} S(i)$ looks like.  As a concrete example, suppose we have $i=1$ to $4$, then:

$$\begin{align*}
S(1)&=S\\
S(2)&=S(1) \cup \{g_{1}{h_{1}}^{-1}\mid g_{1},h_{1}\in S(1)\}\\
S(3)&=S(2) \cup \{g_{2}{h_{2}}^{-1}\mid g_{2},h_{2}\in S(2)\}\\
S(4)&=S(3) \cup \{g_{3}{h_{3}}^{-1}\mid g_{3},h_{3}\in S(3)\}\\
S(5)&=S(4) \cup \{g_{4}{h_{4}}^{-1}\mid g_{4},h_{4}\in S(4)\},
\end{align*}$$
and
$$\langle S \rangle=\bigcup_{i=1}^{5} S(i)=\{g_{1}{h_{1}}^{-1}\}\cup\{g_{2}{h_{2}}^{-1}\}\cup\{g_{3}{h_{3}}^{-1}\}\cup\{g_{4}{h_{4}}^{-1}\}.$$

Am I understanding the definition correctly and also, do the union symbol mean concatenation of elements from each $S(i)$?  thank you in advance

Comment: No, the union symbol means union. Are you familiar with the basic set operations of union, intersection? I'm also not sure why you stopped after 5 steps in your example, but it is supposed to go to infinity.

Comment: @CaptainLama do you mean for $\langle S \rangle$ in the case of $i$ up to 4, it looks like $\langle S \rangle=\bigcup_{i=1}^{5} S(i)=\{g_{1}{h_{1}}^{-1}\}\cup\{g_{2}{h_{2}}^{-1}\}\cup\{g_{3}{h_{3}}^{-1}\}\cup\{g_{4}{h_{4}}^{-1}\}$?  I let $i$ to be some finite value as a concrete example.  I know it can go to infinity.

Comment: Don't force line breaks. You may be messing up displays; the renderer is dynamic and takes into account the users' interface, by putting in `<br/>` codes you break that dynamism and may create terrible  rendering. And don't use math mode for italic text. Math italic is *not* the same as regular italic. Use `*text*` outside of math mode to get italic text.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I need to go over that MathJax reference page with someone who have more experience with both LaTex and MathJax.  Also, can you please tell me if I am understanding the definition in my post correctly.

Comment: No, you are not. What you wrote is a mess. For starters, the definition of $\langle S\rangle$ doesn't stop at $5$ just because **you** stopped at $5$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin then I don't know explicitly what property 2 and hence how to write out property 3.  Can you use a simple example to illustrate please.

Answer (score 4):

No, you are not understanding properly.

Suppose $S=\{x,y\}$. Then
$$\begin{align}
S(1) &= S = \{x,y\}.\\
S(2) &= S(1)\cup \{rs^{-1}\mid r,s\in S(1)\}\\
&= \{x,y\} \cup \{ xx^{-1}, xy^{-1}, yx^{-1}, yy^{-1}\} \tag{1}\\
&= \{x,y\}\cup \{e,xy^{-1},yx^{-1}\}\\
&= \{e,x,y,xy^{-1},yx^{-1}\}.\\
S(3) &= S(2)\cup \{rs^{-1}\mid r,s\in S(2)\}\\
&= \{e,x,y,xy^{-1},yx^{-1}\} \cup T
\end{align}$$
where $T$ consists of the 25 elements you get by selecting two elements from $S(2)$ and performing the operation. So $T$ will consist of the elements
$$\begin{align*}
&ee^{-1},\ ex^{-1},\ ey^{-1},\ e(xy^{-1})^{-1}, e(yx^{-1})^{-1},\\
&xe^{-1},\ xxx^{-1},\ xy^{-1},\ x(xy^{-1})^{-1}, x(yx^{-1})^{-1},\\
&ye^{-1},\ yx^{-1},\ yy^{-1},\ y(xy^{-1})^{-1}, y(yx^{-1})^{-1},\\
&(xy^{-1})e^{-1},\ (xy^{-1})x^{-1},\ (xy^{-1})y^{-1},\ (xy^{-1})(xy^{-1})^{-1}, (xy^{-1})(yx^{-1})^{-1},\\
&(yx^{-1})e^{-1},\ (yx^{-1})x^{-1},\ (yx^{-1})y^{-1},\ (yx^{-1})(xy^{-1})^{-1}, (yx^{-1})(yx^{-1})^{-1}.\\
\end{align*}$$
Now, some of those elements are repeats. Once everything is said and done, you get
$$\begin{align*}
&e,\ x^{-1},\ y^{-1},\ yx^{-1},\ xy^{-1},\ x,\ xyx^{-1},\ y,\ y^2x^{-1},\ yxy^{-1},\\
&xyx^{-1},\ xy^{-2},\ xy^{-1}xy^{-1},\ yx^{-2},\ yx^{-1}y^{-1},\ yx^{-1}yx^{-1}.
\end{align*}$$
So
$$ S(3) = \left\{\begin{array}{l}
e,x,y,xy^{-1},yx^{-1},x^{-1},y^{-1},yx^{-1},\\
xy^{-1},x,xyx^{-1},y,y^2x^{-1},yxy^{-1},xyx^{-1},\\
xy^{-2},xy^{-1}xy^{-1},yx^{-2},yx^{-1}y^{-1},yx^{-1}yx^{-1}\end{array}\right\}.$$
Some of these may simplify or be equal to each other depending on your specific group. But the next term $S(4)$, will require you to take all of these 20 elements, and add the $(20)(20)=400$ products that you get by picking any two of these 20 elements (repetitions allowed), and multiplying the first times the inverse of the second. And so on.

At the end, $\langle S\rangle$ contains **all** the elements you can get this way, at **any** level, not just whatever level you decide you've had enough with and stop. You have to keep going to consider $S(4)$, $S(5)$, $S(6)$, etc. The final equation says
$$\langle S\rangle = S(1)\cup S(2)\cup S(3)\cup\cdots \cup S(n)\cup S(n+1)\cup\cdots$$
with no end.

---

For instance, consider the dihedral group of order $8$, which you are denoting $D_4$,
$$D_4=\langle r,s\mid r^4=s^2=1, sr=r^3s\rangle = \{e,r,r^2,r^3,s,rs,r^2s,r^3s\},$$
and consider $S=\{r^2,s\}$.

Then
$$\begin{align*}
S(1) &= S = \{r^2,s\}\\
S(2) &= S(1)\cup \{gh^{-1}\mid g,h\in S(1)\}\\
&= \{r^2,s\}\cup\{ r^2(r^2)^{-1}, r^2s^{-1},s(r^2)^{-1},ss^{-1}\}\\
&= \{r^2,s\}\cup \{e,r^2s,sr^2,e\}\\
&= \{r^2,s\}\cup\{e,r^2s\}\quad\text{because }sr^{2}=r^{-2}s=r^2s\\
&= \{e,r^2,s,r^2s\}.\\
S(3) &= S(2)\cup \{gh^{-1}\mid gh\in S(2)\}\\
&= \{e,r^2,s,r^2s\} \cup \left\{\begin{array}{l}
ee^{-1},e(r^2)^{-1}, es^{-1},e(r^2s)^{-1},\\
r^2e^{-1},r^2(r^2)^{-1},r^2s^{-1},r^2(r^2s)^{-1}\\
se^{-1},s(r^2)^{-1},ss^{-1},s(r^2s)^{-1}\\
(r^2s)e^{-1},(r^2s)(r^2)^{-1},(r^2s)s^{-1},(r^2s)(r^2s)^{-1}
\end{array}\right\}\\
&= \{e,r^2,s,r^2s\}\cup \{e,r^2,s,r^2s\}\\
&= \{e,r^2,s,r^2s\} = S(2).
\end{align*}$$
Since $S(3)=S(2)$, it now follows that $S(4)=S(3)=S(2)$, $S(5)=S(4)=S(2)$, etc. So
$$\langle S\rangle = S(1)\cup S(2)\cup\cdots \cup S(n)\cup\cdots = S(1)\cup S(2) = \{e,r^2,s,r^2s\}.$$

Here the process ended after finitely  many steps (this is a consequence of working in a finite group, or more generally of $\langle S\rangle$ being a finite group). But you may need to keep going indefinitely even in very simply groups. Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}$ under addition, and $S=\{2\}$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
S(1) &= S = \{2\}.\\
S(2) &=\{2\}\cup \{g-h\mid g,h\in S(1)\}\\
&= \{2\}\cup\{2-2\} = \{2,0\}.\\
S(3) &= \{0,2\}\cup\{g-h\mid g,h\in S(2)\}\\
&= \{0,2\}\cup\{0-0, 0-2,2-0,2-2\} = \{0,2,-2\}.\\
S(4) &= \{0,2,-2\}\cup\{0-0,0-2,0-(-2),2-0,2-2,2-(-2),-2-0,-2-2,-2-(-2)\}\\
&= \{0,2,-2,4,-4\}.\\
S(5) &= \{0,2,-2,4,-4\}\cup\{0,-2,2,-4,4,6,-6,8,-8\}\\
&=\{0,2,-2,4,-4,6,-6,8,-8\}.
\end{align*}$$
At each step, you will add more elements; with $S(6)$, you will add $-10 = -2-8$, $10=2-(-8)$, $12=6-(-6)$, $-12$, $14$, $-14$, $16$, and $-16$. Etc.  In the end, you get that
$$\langle S\rangle = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}S(i) = \{0,2,-2,4,-4,6,-6,8,-8,10,-10,\ldots,2k,-2k,\ldots\} = 2\mathbb{Z}$$
but you cannot stop at any particular $S(n)$, you need to keep going through all natural number indices.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation.  The definition makes sense now.  I wish i can read math prose as well as you do.